# Unique Pointer nullptr comparison

Tags: c++

I have a simple AutoPtr class

```
template<typename T>
class AutoPtr
{
public:
    explicit AutoPtr(T* p = NULL):m_ptr(p){}
    ~AutoPtr()
    {
        if(m_ptr)
            delete m_ptr;
        m_ptr = NULL;
    }

    T&  operator*(){return *m_ptr;}
    T*  operator->(){return m_ptr;}
    T* Get()        { return m_ptr; }

private:
    T*    m_ptr;
};
```

How would I make this class usable for operations such as:

```
AutoPtr<MyClass> ptr;
if(ptr)
{
    // Do stuff!
}
```

I have tried

```
bool operator==(const T& other) { return m_ptr == other.m_ptr; }
bool operator!=(const T& other) { return !(*this == other);}
```

and

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const AutoPtr<T>& x, void* y) {  return x.Get() == y; }
template<typename T>
bool operator!=(const AutoPtr<T>& x, void* y) {  return x.Get() != y; }
```

This is not homework, I may not use c++11 or boost.

Comment: `explicit operator bool() const { return m_ptr != nullptr; }`?

Comment: Thank you. Put it as a answer and I will mark it as correct. Or close as trivial I suppose.

Comment: @marsh You can't use explicit conversion operators before C++11, so lose the `explicit` and the code in the comment should work. You may also want to look into the [safe bool idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool) to prevent undesirable implicit conversions.

Comment: @marsh I believe that only works for C++11. Do you have C++11 support? If so, why not use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Yes thank you Praetorian I got it working, As I said in my question I do not have c++11 support James.

Comment: @Praetorian is correct about the safe bool idiom here is another [useful link](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

Comment: @marsh Yes, you did state that in your question. :) My mistake.

Comment: @marsh: about you d-tor, `~AutoPtr(){delete m_ptr;}` is enough. `delete NULL` does nothing.

Comment: I get that the if statement may not be needed but if you do not set the m_ptr to  NULL then how will someone who still has the pointer check if its valid or not?

Comment: Your class doesn't follow the Rule of Three, so fix that before trying to use it

Comment: @marsh the object is destroyed after the destructor is run, it is not possible to "check it is valid" on an object that does not exist

Comment: Someone could have called Get on the class and be holding the pointer? Also I will implement the rule of three. Good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the operator the following way

```
explicit operator bool() const { return m_ptr != NULL; }
```

If your compiler does not support specifier explicit then the other approach is to define operator

```
operator const void *() const { return m_ptr; }
```

In the last case you may use your class with `operator <<`

For example

```
std::cout << AutoPtr() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Do I still need the safe bool if I use the second example?

Comment: @marsh You may use the both operators.

Comment: For anyone else reading, a slight downside of using operator const void *() const { return m_ptr; } in this case is that people can now call delete on my autoPtr class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known idiom for implementing safe bool operator: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool